# Normal Distribution and Dependent Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a random variable X, that is Normally distributed, and then I have another Random Variable Y, which is some sort of a function of X..... (e.g. Y = f(X)).

Is it possible for the Dependent Random Variable Y to follow a Normal Distribution?

If it is, then Under what conditions Y can have a normal distribution and under what conditions Y cannot have a normal distribution?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**
Let $F_X(x) = \mathbb{P}[X \le x]$ be the CDF of $X$. Then assuming $f$ is invertible,
$$
F_Y(x) = \mathbb{P}[Y \le y] = \mathbb{P}[f(X) \le y],
$$
and you would like to claim somehow that this equals
$$
\mathbb{P}[f^{-1}(f(X)) \le f^{-1}(y)]
 = \mathbb{P}[X \le f^{-1}(y)]
 = F_X\left(f^{-1}(y)\right).
$$

But under what conditions on $f$ can you make that claim?

Comment: sorry, but this is too much over my head. I am not a math major, and these fancy equations always scares me..... Could you continue on your hint please?